# How to map multiple intents to one handler in dialogflow-fulfillment?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

There are multiple intents in my bot that can use a single handler.

In v1, this was done by

```
function handler (agent){
  //handler code
}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Intent1', handler);
intentMap.set('Intent2', handler);
```

How can the same be achieved in v2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do this

```
app.intent('Intent1', (conv) => {
   //handler code
});

app.intent('Intent2', 'Intent1');
```